# Migrating existing entities to use entity groups

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, google-cloud-datastore, eventual-consistency

I am working with a legacy GAE system, using JDO 2.3, which does not use entity groups, but I now wish use entity groups, to take advantage of transactions. Having added a one-to-many relationship on two entity types, this works correctly for new entities created, but causes problems when working with existing legacy entities without the parent-child relationship (unable to delete the child entity).

How do I migrate the existing legacy entities to use the new schema? I have tried updating the parent on the child classes but received a `org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreRelationFieldManager$ChildWithoutParentException` ... `A parent cannot be established or changed once an object has been persisted.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **you can still use Transactions outside of an entity-group** - it's called cross-group transactions (XG transactions). You are limited to **25 entity groups** in the transaction though.

*Note: in your case, every entity is an entity group.*

The entity-group of an entity is an immutable property defined at creation time. What this means is that you would need to delete and then write a new entity with the correct parent set, in a transaction of course.

Comment: Ah yes, I am aware of XG transactions. I should have clarified in my original question that I need transactions involving more than 25 entities :D. Nevertheless, your second part of the answer was what I needed. I was hoping there would be a way to do without creating a new entity type though, because the encoded-pk of the original entity was getting used and stored in business logic and other entities.